# Missing the raster interpolation plugin in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, interpolation

I can't find the `Raster ‣ Interpolation` plugin in QGIS 3,
I tried to search for it through the plugin's installation applet following [this tutorial](https://bit.ly/3E0twhI) and searched for 'interpolation', but it doesn't appear!
I searched for it in the Processing Toolbox, but no luck as well!

Has it been deprecated? or what am I making wrong?

I have QGIS 3.24.1Tisler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct, the owner of this Plugin [does not support](https://github.com/3nids/rasterinterpolation/issues/9) anything above QGIS 3.0.

Comment: Do you know any similar alternative?

Answer (score 4):

The interpolation tools are located under the Processing toolbox, if you write `interpolation` in the search box you will find all the interpolation tools:

[image]

I am using QGIS 3.22.4.

Comment: You are right, I found them, but the raster interpolation plugin is not one of them, they don`t have the same features and functionalities like the deprecated one.

Comment: The plugin is deprecated because it becomes a core tool inside QGIS, which you can see under the processing toolbox. However, under the toolbox you have several interpolation tools instead of one plugin. What exactly are you looking for and you didn’t find in the interpolation toolbox?

Comment: Here's the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/spatial_analysis_interpolation.html) on those four interpolation tools. See the examples it has. Do any of those match what you are trying to do?

Comment: @ahmadhanb Actually, I am novice to the GIS tools, I was following some tutorials to be able to convert my CSV data to layers. almost all the tutorials depend on this plugin! that's why I asked about it, and as I am a novice, I still can't tell the difference between the old plugin and the new core ones.